# Getting control flow error once I'm navigating back to webdriver methods after completing async operation using control flow

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angular-promise, control-flow

When my Protractor scripts is moving from async methods to normal webdriver operations it's failing and giving me error as:

> Failed: Cannot assign to read only property 'stack' of Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "[ng:test] no injector found for element argument to getTestability\nhttp://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/ng/test"
>   Stack:
>      at C:\Users\DELL pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:377:21
>           at Promise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\DELL pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1329:14)
>           at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\DELL pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2790:14)
>           at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\DELL pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2773:21)
>           at C:\Users\DELL pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2652:27
>           at C:\Users\DELL pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:639:7
>           at process._tickCallback (node.js:369:9)
>       From: Task: Run it("should be able to reset password") in control flow
>           at Object. (C:\Users\DELL pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:81:14)
>       From asynchronous test:
>       Error
>           at Suite. (E:\newworkspace\TestAngularpjt\src\TestCases\ForgotPasswordForPosse.js:17:2)
>           at Object. (E:\newworkspace\TestAngularpjt\src\TestCases\ForgotPasswordForPosse.js:3:1)
>           at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
>           at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
>           at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
>           at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)

Following is the code of my testcase:

```
    var mailFile= require("../commonUtils/mailFile.js");

describe('Test the Reset flow', function(){

var forgotPswdLink = element(by.css('[ng-click="ForgotPassword()"]'));
//var emailField = element(by.xpath("//*[@class='subtitle']/following-sibling::input"));
var emailField = element(by.model("password_reset['username']"));
//var resetpswdBtn = element(by.xpath('//button[text()="Reset password"]'));
var resetpswdBtn = element(by.xpath('//button[text()="Send reset link"]'));
var paswdResendMsg = element(by.css('.email-notification'));
var newPwdOne = element(by.model("password_reset['newPassword']"));
var newPwdTwo = element(by.model("password_reset['newPasswordConfirmation']"));
var submitButton = element(by.id('submit'));

var mailFi = new mailFile();

it('should be able to reset password', function(){
    var flow = protractor.promise.controlFlow();
    var emailAdd= "usernew@mailosaur.io";

    browser.get('https://secure.testurl.com/forgot-password');

    emailField.sendKeys(emailAdd);
    resetpswdBtn.click();
    expect(paswdResendMsg.getText()).toEqual('An email with instructions will be sent to the email address for this account.');

    function emailTokenValues(){

    var Mailosaur = require("mailosaur")("Your_API_key");
    var mailbox = new Mailosaur.Mailbox("MailboxId");

    console.log("Here it begins!");
    var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
    mailbox.getEmailsByRecipient(emailAdd, function(err, emails) {

    err;
    var htmlBody = emails[0].html.body;
    var regEx = "token=[A-Z|a-z|0-9|%]+";
    var myArray = htmlBody.match(regEx);

    //var tokenVal = myArray[0].split("=");

    console.log(myArray[0]);

    var defaultUrl= "https://secure.testurl.com/reset-password?"

    var newURL = defaultUrl+myArray[0];
    console.log(newURL);
    browser.get(newURL);

    //console.log(emails[0].html.body);

    console.log("Are you even going inside?");
    return deferred.fulfill();

});
deferred.promise;
browser.sleep(5000);
}

flow.execute(emailTokenValues);

newPwdOne.sendKeys('Welcome@123');
newPwdTwo.sendKeys('Welcome@123');
submitButton.click();   
});});
```

Once the "flow.execute(emailTokenValues)" get executed then it's giving error while looking to perform "newPwdOne.sendKeys('Welcome@123');" operation. Any suggestion what I'm doing wrong here?